# onchange not working on calculator

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <title>Calculate your MPG</title>

       <script type="text/javascript">
          function calcMPG() {
             var startMiles = parseInt(document.getElementByID('start').value);
             var endMiles = parseInt(document.getElementByID('end').value);
             var gallons = parseInt(document.getElementByID('gallons').value);
             var mpg = 0;
             if (isNaN(startMiles) || isNaN(endMiles) || isNaN(gallons)) {
                alert("Please enter numeric values!");
             } elseif (gallons === 0) {
                alert("Cannot enter 0 gallons!");
             } else {
                mpg = (endMiles - startMiles) / gallons;
                document.getElementByID("miles").value = mpg.toString();
             }
          }
       </script>
    </head>

    <body> 

       <h2>Enter your starting mileage, ending mileage, and gallons used to calculate your miles per gallon.</h2>

       <form name="calcmpg" action="calcMPG()">
          Starting Mileage:<br />
          <input type="text" id="start" value="0" required="required" onchange="calcMPG()" /><br />

          Ending Mileage: <br />
          <input type="text" id="end" value="0" required="required" onchange="calcMPG()" /><br />

          Gallons Used: <br />
          <input type="text" id="gallons" value="10" required="required" onchange="calcMPG()" /><br /><br />

          MPG: <br />
          <input type="text" id="miles" /><br /><br />

          <input type="reset" value="Clear Fields" /> <br /><br /> 
      
       </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

It is passing validation at W3Schools but it won't calculate the MPG or give the alert if numbers are not entered. I have tried pretty much everything I can think of and I am at my wit's end. I think it is not even calling the Javascript function.

Comment: can you throw this in a codepen?\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, but, you had a lot of syntax errors...

Using `oninput` instead of `onchange` gives you the effect you wanted.

Also, I made it so you didn't need `oninput="calcMPG()"` in the HTML, as I find it better to handle events in the script.  Here is what I ended up doing:

```
calcMPG = function() {
  var startMiles = parseInt(document.getElementById('start').value);
  var endMiles = parseInt(document.getElementById('end').value);
  var gallons = parseInt(document.getElementById('gallons').value);
  var mpg = 0;
  if (isNaN(startMiles) || isNaN(endMiles) || isNaN(gallons)) {
    document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML="Please enter numeric values!";
  } else if (gallons === 0) {
    document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML="Cannot enter 0 gallons!";
  } else {
    mpg = (endMiles - startMiles) / gallons;
    document.getElementById("miles").value = mpg.toString();
  }
}

document.getElementById("gallons").oninput=calcMPG;
document.getElementById("start").oninput=calcMPG;
document.getElementById("end").oninput=calcMPG;
```

But I noticed a syntax error while fixing...  `getElementByID` should be `getElementById`, (`ID` vs `Id`, JavaScript is case sensitive).

So, I also fixed up your HTML a little bit:

```
<h2>Enter your starting mileage, ending mileage, and gallons used to calculate your miles per gallon.</h2>

<form name="calcmpg" action="calcMPG()">
  Starting Mileage:<br />
  <input type="text" id="start" value="0" required="required" /><br />

  Ending Mileage: <br />
  <input type="text" id="end" value="0" required="required" /><br />

  Gallons Used: <br />
  <input type="text" id="gallons" value="10" required="required" /><br /><br />

  MPG: <br />
  <input type="text" id="miles" /><br /><br />

  <input type="reset" value="Clear Fields" /> <br /><br /> 

</form>
<div id="errors"></div>
```

Note, this all replaces whatever is in the `<body>` element.

Lastly, here is a JSFiddle, to show you that it gives you your desired effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/arjn2mmj/1/

*Another note:* Since you're a new user, I'll let you know a tip, if you click the green checkmark, it will give me and you reputation.  This helps both of us out.  And it also tells me that I help you with your problem.

---

**EDIT**

To use `onchange` as an alternative, you can just replace the `oninput` in the script.

```
document.getElementById("gallons").onchange=calcMPG;
document.getElementById("start").onchange=calcMPG;
document.getElementById("end").onchange=calcMPG;
```

This works /almost/ the same, you just have to click out of the input field when you enter a new value.

See the new JS fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/arjn2mmj/3/

Comment: I green checked you anyway, but my teacher specifically said that I needed to use onchange. Is there any way to make it work?